# Gitlab API Update existing file in repository giving 400 error in rest template

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, gitlab-api

I am trying to edit existing file in a repo using gitlab v4 api,
When I tried to edit file using postman rest client it executes without any issue, 200 status returned.
When I tried the same with SpringBoot RestTemplate, I am always ending up with 400 bad request error. I am completely dont know what actually happening.
Rest URL : https://domainname/api/v4/projects/51/repository/files/src%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fapplication.yml

Request object printed using LOG is :

```
[branch=master, content=server:port: value, commit_message=port number updated, file_path=src%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fapplication.yml]
```

resttemplate API call,

```
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(request, header);
    restTemplate.exchange(gitlabApiUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Object.class);
```

When I tried the same request body with postman, Im getting 200 success

This is the rest end point, https://domainname/api/v4/projects/:projectId/repository/files/:file_path

Does anyone have any idea what is happening.

Reference doc : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository

Comment: check your `file_path` has been encoded properly both in url query param and request object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an alternate option of `COMMIT` functionality in gitlab.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions

Comment: As an alternate I can use this method and it is working. But as per documentation by gitlaab `file_edit` option is still not working